# How to wrap a raw pointer into a shared_ptr and prevent shared_ptr from deleting the object?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I need to wrap a raw pointer into a `shared_ptr` in order to pass it to a function. The function doesn't hold any reference to the input object once it returns.

```
{
  MyClass i;
  shared_ptr<MyClass> p(&i);
  f(p);
  // BAD: shared_ptr will delete i.
}
```

How to prevent `shared_ptr` from deleting the referenced object?

Comment: You could give it an empty deleter.

Comment: WHy would you want to do that?  i is already on the stack, so there's no point in using a smart pointer-  in fact as you see a smart pointer screws it up.  If you need to pass a pointer to it somewhere, use the raw pointer from &i

Comment: @chris That should work. I will probably go with this solution. Thanks!

Comment: The function should not accept a shared pointer if it's not going to have shared ownership of that object. The function should accept an observing pointer, like a raw pointer or a reference wrapper. Or possibly a reference

Comment: @GabeSechan I agree. But I don't have control over the function implementation.

Comment: @Andy I generally agree but there are situations (although this isn’t one) where ownership should be handled transparently. As an example, .NET (yes, yes) has `Pen` objects which need to be disposed, but ther are also cached `Pen` objects for OS colours which **must not** be disposed. A class which should transparently use a pen and discard it afterwards essentially cannot be written, which makes some architectures unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Just wondering, what is the real piece of code that does this? I'd be interested to see exactly what it does.

Comment: @chris I'm writing a thrift server. I implemented a Handler class which handles the service calls and I need to start the running server with something like `start(shared_ptr<Handler>)`. I had a member function in my Handler class which wraps `this` into a shared_ptr and passes it to `start()`.

Comment: @Konrad: I'm not sure I understand what you mean (I am not a .NET programmer): basically you're saying that one may want to write a function that accepts both a regular `Pen` object and system `Pen` object, and the first one should be released when the function exits, while the latter shouldn't, correct? But in that case, why not letting the function *never* release the object, if it's not going to store any reference to it? The responsibility would belong to the caller then

Comment: @Andy You understood correctly. But letting the caller handle the lifetime makes the usage of the class more complex, and the handling problem actually bubbles upwards in the call, rather than staying deep in the API. I’d like to essentially “fire & forget” the `Pen` resource.

Comment: @Konrad: OK, I think I got it. So basically you're passing to the function both the object and instructions on how to dispose it when the function is done, but encapsulated into one single thing - a shared pointer - so you can forget about this object. Makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) alluded to in the comments, write an empty deleter:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct empty_delete
{
    empty_delete() /* noexcept */
    {
    }

    template <typename U>
    empty_delete(const empty_delete<U>&,
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value
        >::type* = nullptr) /* noexcept */
    {
    }

    void operator()(T* const) const /* noexcept */
    {
        // do nothing
    }
};
```

Example of use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct noisy
{
    noisy() { std::cout << "alive" << std::endl; }
    ~noisy() { std::cout << "dead" << std::endl; }

    noisy(const noisy&);
    noisy& operator=(const noisy&);
};

template <typename T>
void take(T& yours)
{
    std::cout << "Taking..." << std::endl;
    {
        auto mine = std::move(yours);
    }
    std::cout << "Took." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<noisy> a(new noisy());
    std::shared_ptr<noisy> b(new noisy());
    std::unique_ptr<noisy, empty_delete<noisy>> c(new noisy());
    std::shared_ptr<noisy> d(new noisy(), empty_delete<noisy>());

    take(a);
    take(b);
    take(c);
    take(d);
}
```

Output:

> alive
>   alive
>   alive
>   alive
>   Taking...
>   dead
>   Took.
>   Taking...
>   dead
>   Took.
>   Taking...
>   Took.
>   Taking...
>   Took.

Of course, this example leaks memory.

Answer (score 0):

In case of .NET/clr as mentioned in the comments, you should implement `ref class`, pass the managed handle `^` and let the garbage collector manage the lifetime.

```cpp
ref class MyClassManaged : public Pen
{
public:
  MyClassManaged() : Pen{}, native_{ new MyClass{} } { }
  ~MyClassManaged() { this->!MyClassManaged(); }
  !MyClassManaged() { delete native_; }
private:
  MyClass* native_;
};
//...
{
  MyClassManaged^ i = gcnew MyClassManaged{};
  fManaged(i);
}
```

---

**TL;DR Simply keep another copy of the `shared_ptr<MyClass>` alive, and allocate `i` on the heap instead of the stack if you still need it.**

Scenario 1

```cpp
{
  shared_ptr<MyClass> another_p;
  {
    MyClass i;
    shared_ptr<MyClass> p(&i);
    f(p);
    // p has not deleted i yet
    another_p = p; // increment reference count
    // p will decrement the reference count
    // i will be deleted due to stack unwinding
  }
  // another_p still holds a reference to where i was on the stack
  if (another_p)
    something(); // yes, something() will be invoked
  else
    nothing(); // no, nothing() won't run here
  // another_p will attempt to delete again if not the shared_ptr is not copied elsewhere
}
```

Scenario 2

```cpp
{
  shared_ptr<MyClass> another_p;
  {
    auto p = make_shared<MyClass>();
    auto& i = *p;
    f(p);
    // p has not deleted i
    another_p = p; // increment reference count
    // p will decrement the reference count
    // i will be NOT deleted
  }
  // another_p still holds a reference to where i was on the heap
  if (another_p)
    something(); // yes, something() will be invoked
  else
    nothing(); // no, nothing() won't run here
  // another_p will attempt to delete again if not the shared_ptr is not copied elsewhere
}
// it will finally be deleted now
```

Simply keep another copy of the shared_ptr alive; no need to mess with an empty deleter alike.